# Handling CTRL-C during UART polling in Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux, kernel, uart

I have a syscall read, like so:

```
ssize_t serp_read(struct file *filep, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *offp){
        ssize_t cnt;
        char *buffer;
        int i;

        buffer = kmalloc(count * sizeof(char), GFP_KERNEL);

        for (i = 0; i != count; ++i) {
            buffer[i] = UART_read();
            if(buffer[i] == '\n')
                break;
        }

        cnt = copy_to_user(buf, buffer, i);
        kfree(buffer);
        if(cnt) {
        printk("Error in copy_to_user() cnt is %d\n", cnt);
        i -= cnt; /* bytes successfully copied */
        }

        return i; 
}
```

And the UART_read() is

```
unsigned char UART_read(void){
     unsigned int buf;
     if( ( inb(UART + UART_LSR) & UART_LSR_FE ) == 1){
       printk("KERNEL - Framing error"); return -1;}
     else if( ( inb(UART + UART_LSR) & UART_LSR_PE ) == 1){
       printk("KERNEL - Parity error"); return -1;}
     else if( ( inb(UART + UART_LSR) & UART_LSR_OE ) == 1){
       printk("KERNEL - Overrun error"); return -1;}

     while( ( ( inb(UART_LSR + UART) ) & UART_LSR_DR ) == 0 ){
             schedule();
     }
     buf = inb(UART);
     return (char)buf;
}
```

And in my test program I invoke it

```
    rb = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if ( rb < 0){
        perror("Error");
    }
    else {
        buffer[rb] = '\0';
    }
```

So, from the moment I invoke it in the test program, I can't get out unless the UART gets some characters. But I want to be able to interrupt the process. Can I do a normal handler to handle a CTRL-C? Or do I have to do something different for the same effect? And if the handler is called, where is the kernel program going to go afterwards?
Or what would happen in the kernel if I just had a normal handler in the test program? Would it work at all?

Also, kernel code is one program and the test program is another program altogether.

Comment: Following on from this, what sort of behaviour would `buffer[rb] = '\0';` result in, given that `rb` is `1` and the only valid index is `0`?

Comment: The buffer from the test program holds 1024 chars, that sizeof is of no issue to the problem and works. The kernel code is one program, the test program is another program entirely.

Comment: No. Same issue. Suppose `read` returns 1024, and the only valid indexes are `0 .. 1023`? There's an off-by-one. Perhaps you meant `rb = read(fd, buffer, sizeof buffer - 1);`

Comment: I see. But this application/project won't receive that many characters, so it won't be an issue. I'll alter it though.

Comment: Out of hindsight (after posting my answer), which process is it you want to interrupt? The kernel process, or the user process?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT2: ctrl+c issues a signal(SIGINT) that can be treated with `sigaction()`

-----------IGNORE MODE ON (according to @undefined-behaviour)-------------

this code handles a ctrl+c

EDIT: `while ((a!='A')&&(a!='ctrl+c'));` this was supposed to have the 'ctrl+c' char but stackoverflow doesnt show it (its the decimal/octal/hex: 0003)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> /*_getch*/
#include <termios.h>    /*_getch*/


char getch() {
    /*#include <unistd.h>   //_getch*/
    /*#include <termios.h>  //_getch*/
    char buf=0;
    struct termios old = {0};
    fflush(stdout);
    if(tcgetattr(0, &old) < 0)
        perror("tcsetattr()");
    old.c_lflag&=~ICANON;
    old.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    old.c_cc[VMIN]=1;
    old.c_cc[VTIME]=0;
    if(tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &old) < 0)
        perror("tcsetattr ICANON");
    if(read(0,&buf,1)<0)
        perror("read()");
    old.c_lflag=ICANON;
    old.c_lflag=ECHO;
    if(tcsetattr(0, TCSADRAIN, &old) < 0)
        perror ("tcsetattr ~ICANON");
    printf("%c\n",buf);
    return buf;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char a;
    do{
        a=getch();
        printf("%d-%c \n",a,a);
    }while ((a!='A')&&(a!='ctrl+c'));   /* ctrl+c ;  backspace ;� multi-char cte ; ç 135*/
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want to read characters exclusively from the keyboard. Read the question again, very carefully, in it's entirety. Even if he/she did want to, this would be a silly way to do this. `man getchar`.

Comment: behaviour is right, I don't really think that would work for me.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, either. Don't erase your answer entirely and write a new one; amend to it. That way you're not rendering follow-up discussions gibberish...

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you can do is write a signal handler at your application level which catches SIGINT (ctrl+c) or whatever signal of your choice (provided we can handle those)

and from the signal handle call an IOCTL call to your driver inside kernel
which inturn should reschedule your kernel read may be a change in logic like below

**you need to implement an IOCTL call at kernel** along with this

```
 /** This NO_SIGNAL_FROM_USER is a GLOBAL variable at kernel 
             which should be set based on your IOCTL**/

 while( (( ( inb(UART_LSR + UART) ) & UART_LSR_DR ) == 0 ) && (NO_SIGNAL_FROM_USER)){
             schedule();
     }
```

and a little change at your read

```
for (i = 0; i != count && NO_SIGNAL_FROM_USER ; ++i) {
            buffer[i] = UART_read();
            if(buffer[i] == '\n')
                break;
        }
/*** RESET THE SIGNAL HERE AGAIN ***/
```

P.S - oops forgot may be you need to do some more handling at signal handler also in  your user application, but again that depends i guess.

Comment: I'm still trying to wrap my head around IOCTL in the first place, much less use it like so. But if I ever get to it, I'll come back here.